# Make a string from a View element

Tags: android, seekbar

I have two seekbars in my main activity but I can only use one of them at a time, so I need to retrieve a value `seekbarx` and `seekbary`, store either of them in a string variable to use it forward. I already used `onProgressChange` and `onStopTrackingTouch` but I guess it doesn't hold the value long enough. 
This is what I had for the seekbars

```
        package edu.itdurango.servocontrolyun;

        import java.io.BufferedReader;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.io.InputStreamReader;
        import java.net.MalformedURLException;
        import java.net.URL;
        import java.net.URLConnection;
        import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
        import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

        import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
        import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
        import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
        import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
        import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
        import org.json.JSONObject;

        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.SeekBar;
        import android.widget.TextView;
        import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;


 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
// TODO: adjust ARDUINO_IP_ADDRESS
public final String ARDUINO_IP_ADDRESS = "192.168.1.71";    //Dirección IP del Arduino Yun
public final String TAG = "ArduinoYun";
public String servo;

private SeekBar SeekBarX;                                   //Barra de búsqueda del eje X
private SeekBar SeekBarY;                                   //Barra de búsqueda del eje Y


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SeekBarX = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.barraEjeX);
    /*SeekBarX.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View barraEjeX) {
            servo = "servox/";

        }
    });*/
    SeekBarX.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar barraEjeX) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar barraEjeX) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar barraEjeX, int progressX,
                boolean fromUser) {
            servo = "servox/";
            log("touching X bar. servo = " + servo);                
            QueueX.offer(progressX);
        }
    });

    SeekBarY = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.barraEjeY);
    /*SeekBarY.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View barraEjeY) {
            servo = "servoy/";

        }
    });*/
    SeekBarY.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {         
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar barraEjeY) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar barraEjeY) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar barraEjeY, int progressY,
                boolean fromUser) {
            servo = "servoy/";
            log("touching Y bar. servo = " + servo);
            QueueY.offer(progressY);
        }
        });

}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    mStop.set(false);
    if(sNetworkThreadSend == null){
        sNetworkThreadSend = new Thread(mNetworkRunnableSend);
        sNetworkThreadSend.start();
    }
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    mStop.set(true);
    QueueX.clear();
    QueueX.offer(-1);
    QueueY.clear();
    QueueY.offer(-1);
    if(sNetworkThreadSend != null) sNetworkThreadSend.interrupt();
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void log(String s){
    Log.d(">==< "+TAG+" >==<", s);
}

private ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer> QueueX = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(100);
private ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer> QueueY = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(100);
private AtomicBoolean mStop = new AtomicBoolean(false);

private static Thread sNetworkThreadSend = null;
private final Runnable mNetworkRunnableSend = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        log("starting network thread for sending");  
        String urlBase = "http://"+ARDUINO_IP_ADDRESS+"/arduino/"+servo;
        String url;

        try {
            while(!mStop.get()){
                int val;
                if (servo == "servoy/"){
                    val = QueueY.take();
                        if(val >= 0){
                            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                            url = urlBase.concat(String.valueOf(val));
                            log("executing httpClient request");
                            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
                            log(url);
                    }
                }  
                if (servo == "servox/"){
                    val = QueueX.take();
                        if(val >= 0){
                            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                            url = urlBase.concat(String.valueOf(val));
                            log("executing httpClient request");
                            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
                            log(url);
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        log("returning from network thread for sending");
        sNetworkThreadSend = null;
    }
};  
private static Thread sNetworkThreadReceive = null;
private final Runnable mNetworkRunnableReceive = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        log("starting network thread for receiving");

        String url = "http://"+ARDUINO_IP_ADDRESS+"/data/get/D9";

        while(!mStop.get()){
            try {
                String string = readURL(url);
                String value = "";
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonMain = new JSONObject(string);
                    value = jsonMain.get("value").toString();
                    log("value = "+value);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                updateText(value);

                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        log("returning from network thread for receiving");
        sNetworkThreadReceive = null;
    }
}; 
public void updateText(final String value){
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            textView.setText(value);
        }
    });

} 

public String readURL(String value){
    URL url;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        url = new URL(value);
        URLConnection yc = url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){ 
            builder.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

}

It prints in the LogCat `touching Y bar. servo = servoy/` but when I want to use the servo value it prints `null`.
How can I hold the value for this string?

Comment: You need to provide more information on what your trying to do. Logcat is printing the correct value, since servo = "servoy/". Where does it prints null?

Comment: Where is the log() method defined? Perhaps you meant to use something such as Log.d()? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#d(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Comment: This is the full code for the activity. I'm using the log to see the code is working the way i want. It's supposed to send an address like `http://<ipaddress>/arduino/<servo>/<value>` but what's going `null` in the logcat is the servo string, and I can't send the full address properly.

Comment: By the way, I don't know if the way I declared the two queues has something to do